# Filtering OSGi services using SlingScriptHelper#getService() method

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle, sling

I want to instantiate a service object in my jsp using sling taglib. In normal scenario where the service class is being implemented by only 1 class, its pretty simple:-

```
RegistrationService registrationService = sling.getService(RegistrationService.class);
```

But if the service class has more than 1 implementation classes, then how can we make sure to instantiate object for a particular class.

My java class are like:-
1. Interface: RegistrationService
2. Implementation Class 1:-

```
@Properties({@Property(name = "datasource", value = "SBWS"})
   @Service
   public class RegistrationServiceImpl implements RegistrationService{
   }
```

3. Implementation Class 2:-

```
@Properties({@Property(name = "datasource", value = "SOLR"})
   @Service
   public class RegistrationServiceImpl implements RegistrationService{
   }
```

How can I make sure that using

```
RegistrationService registrationService = sling.getService(RegistrationService.class);
```

in jsp will instantiate service for let say implementation class 1

Comment: Not sure if there is a clean way, but how about having two different interfaces which just extend the RegistrationService interface? You can still define mutliple interfaces in the @Services annotation, but in the jsp you can select the one you need by the specific interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SlingScriptHelper#getServices(...)` method, which allows to specify a filter:

```
RegistrationService[] services = sling.getServices(RegistrationService.class, "(datasource=SBWS)");
if (services.length > 0) {
    // services[0] contains your service
}
```

Getting OSGi service and filtering it via properties is quite low-level stuff, consider moving it from JSP to a Java class.